# Meaning of verb "nose" in "Georgie wanted to pull him over the breakfast bar and nose at his cheeks."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a passage from a [novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ojkGAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> When Neal smiled, he had dimples like parentheses--stubbly parentheses. Georgie wanted to pull him over the breakfast bar and **nose** at his cheeks. (That was her standard response to Neal smiling.) (Though Neal probably wouldn't know that.)

Does *nose* here means putting her nose on his cheeks?

Comment: I think she wanted to pry on his cheeks. [Verb 2nd](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Nose+meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vaMGVtHkJqSl8weQ4a6wCA)

Comment: @Usernew No, definitely not. I recommend you look up the verb *pry* and ask yourself how it could apply to someone's cheeks. As an aside, the preposition most often collocated with *pry* is *into*, not *on*. To Theo (OP): yes, it means rubbing her nose against his cheeks, as a sign of affection. Kinda like when a dog "noses" your hand.

Comment: @DanBron Got it. :)

Comment: ​https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/nose_2 : [intransitive] + adv./prep. (of an animal) to search for something or push something with its nose

Answer (score 1):

As @DanBron has stated in the comment, this is a sign of affection practiced not only by humans, but by numerous members of the animal kingdom. English speakers will be more familiar with the synonym [***nuzzle***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nuzzle?s=t). It means that she would cuddle face to face with her husband.

Allow this lioness to demonstrate:
[image: Lioness nuzzles lion's cheek]